# Make a div the same height as its width in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

I'm trying to make a div height the same width as a col-md-3 in bootstrap so that as the page adjusts it keeps its "squareness". Outside of bootstrap I use vw, but that's not the case here and height 100%; doesn't work. Any ideas?? Needs to be simple and dynamic.

Comment: The div...(<div class="col-md-3"></div>)...needs to have a height that is equal to it's width (which is set by boostrap col md 3) at all times so that its dynamic on all screen sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap make same height as width. Width of the colum is added to padding so that you can get a squared box

```
.col-md-3{width:25%; padding:25%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SHABU89/gee3mzsy/

Answer (score 1):

It has been answered before from what I see.

```
div {
  background:orange;
  width:?%;
  padding-top:?%;
}

width = padding=top
```

See here [css height same as width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width)

Comment: Please link to the previously answered question as a comment in the question.

Comment: The link provided does not exist